# Celery registers task but beat is not scheduling tasks from installed apps

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I'm having issues getting Celery/Celery Beat to schedule any tasks other than the ones in my celery.py file. I can see the tasks register with "celery inspect registered" but the tasks do not run on the schedule.  I've read all of the docs and I'm a hitting a wall. Running Redis on Windows with Ubuntu WSL.

Test- runs fine every 10 seconds and shows up in my shell
PayClosedLines - is registered but doesn't come up in my shell when I run my celery worker.

/proj/proj/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.apps import apps


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
app = Celery('mysite')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()])


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: [0!r}'.format(self.request))


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, test.s('test'), name='add every 10')
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, )
    sender.add_periodic_task(30.0, test.s(), expires=10)


@app.task
def test(arg):
    print(arg)


'''
proj/proj/settings.py
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'


from datetime import timedelta

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'Payout bets every 10 seconds': {
        'task': 'UFCBetting.tasks.PayClosedLines',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10.0),
    },
}
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('UFCBetting.tasks',)
```

proj/app/task.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .MyBookieTools import get_odds
from .models import BettingLines, Bets, CustomUser

from celery import task, shared_task


@task(name='UpdateLinesTable')
def UpdateLinesTable():
    odds = get_odds()
    for odd in odds:
        bl = BettingLines()
        bl.fighter = odd[0]
        bl.line = odd[1]
        bl.save()


@shared_task
def PayClosedLines():
    unpaid_lines = BettingLines.objects.filter(result="W").exclude(payment_status=True)
    print(unpaid_lines)
    for line in unpaid_lines:
        print(line)
        if line.result == "W":
            unpaid_bets = Bets.objects.filter(line_id=line.id)
            print(unpaid_bets)
            for bet in unpaid_bets:
                user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=bet.placed_by_id)
                user.balance = user.balance + line.payout(amount=bet.bet_amount)
                user.save()
        line.payment_status = 1
        line.save()
    print("Closed lines paid.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your settings do not have the `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER` constant.

If you add this to settings, you don't need to use the `--scheduler` option

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = `django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`
```

Answer (score 1):

I had django-celery-beat installed so I needed to start my beat worker like this.

```
celery -A mysite beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

instead of the usual

```
celery -A mysite beat
```